# Using Sendmail wildcard receipts /etc/mail/virtusertable

Tags: sendmail, wildcard, wildcards, email

I am trying to define wildcard receipts in SendMail, from what I read in this document http://www.sendmail.org/m4/features.html#virtusertable I understand that this would be a correct syntax inside /etc/mail/virtusertable

```
old+*@domain1.com   root@domain2.com
adrian@domain1.com  root@domain2.com
```

I would expect first rule to match a receipt like old243523@domain1.com but it doesn't. The second rule works ok so I assume that localdomains and similar things are all configured correctly, but how to match a wildcard like in first rule? Sending to old243523@domain1.com returns the "not such user" error.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like by supporting wildcard receipts of this form in virtusertable:

    old+*@domain1.com   root@domain2.com

sendmail actually accepts emails sent to "old+2342@domain1.com", "old+blabla@domain1.com", etc.
So it will NOT accept without the plus: oldblabla@domain1.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would expect first rule to match a receipt like old243523@domain1.com but it doesn't

Yes. It doesn't and **must not**. + sign have special meaning in virtusertable

> but how to match a wildcard like in first rule?

Any plussed address, in which + is part of localpart will be matched

If you want transform old*@domain1.com into old+*@domain1.com (for processing later in virtuser) you can use regex map in LOCAL_RULE_0 to rewrite
Just tonote - debug sequences of virtusertable lookup using
sendmail -d60.5 -bv old123@domain1.com